# Contact form not saving in the Database , is it the views or the HTML?

Tags: html, django, django-views

I have an issue in Django where the contact form  after being filled  out doesn't save in the database  unless I just filled out the message text area :

My views :

```
def CV_page(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():

            # Save form data to Django models
            contact = Contact(name= form.cleaned_data['name'],
                              email= form.cleaned_data['email'],
                              phone= form.cleaned_data['phone'],
                              message= form.cleaned_data['message'])
            contact.save()

            # Send email to admin
            send_mail('CV-Website-contact',
                      form.cleaned_data['message'],
                      form.cleaned_data['email'],
                      ['xxxx@xxxx.com', form.cleaned_data['email']])

            return HttpResponse('success') #HttpResponseRedirect('success/') # create a success page
        else:
            form = ContactForm()
    else:
        form = ContactForm()

    context = {'Abouts': latest_description, 'form': form, 'categories': categories, 'portfolios': portfolios, 'pdf': final_pdf_link}
    return render(request, 'cv_page.html', context)
```

models.py

```
class Contact(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True, primary_key=True, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, null=False, blank=True)
    phone = PhoneNumberField(null=True, blank=True, unique=False)
    message = models.CharField(max_length=2500, null=True, blank=True)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=datetime.datetime.now)
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=datetime.datetime.now)
```

forms.py

```
class ContactForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Contact
        fields = ['name', 'email', 'phone', 'message']
```

my HTML:

```
<!-- Contact Section-->
<section class="page-section" id="contact">
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Contact Section Heading-->
        <h2 class="page-section-heading text-center text-uppercase text-secondary mb-0">Contact Me</h2>
        <!-- Icon Divider-->

        <!-- Contact Section Form-->
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-xl-7">

                <form method="post">
                {% csrf_token %}
                    {{form.as_p}}
                    <div class="form-actions">
                          <button type="submit">Send</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

I don't understand why it would only save if there is only the message text area filled out ?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

As you've defined the model already in the `forms.py` you can simply save the form by:

```
form = ContactForm(request.POST)
if form.is_valid():
    # Save form data to Django models
    form.save()
    
    # Send email to admin
    # ... your additional code here
```

also add `action=""` in your HTML-form tag:

```
<form method="post" action="">
```

The `action` argument defines the url for the post request. An empty string will load the same page again. You can also define a custom url.

Everything else looks fine.

**Edit 1:** *(comment 1)*

The issue with the reload is because your `form.is_valid()` fails and then your page reloads:

```
if form.is_valid():
    # ... your code

else:
    form = ContactForm()
```

Remove the last two lines of the code above. If your form fails youre page gets reloaded like before but you'll see the errors in your form.

Here's the working snippet:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = ContactForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():

        # Save form data to Django models
        form.save()

        # Send email to admin
        send_mail('CV-Website-contact',
                  form.cleaned_data['message'],
                  form.cleaned_data['email'],
                  ['xxxx@xxxx.com', form.cleaned_data['email']])

        return HttpResponse('success')

else:
    form = ContactForm()
```

Comment: it only works if I filled out only the section message otherwise it reloads the page ?

Comment: The error find :
--> it is the phone from the models.py that cause the problem
--> I had to reformat the column phone using  charfield  and regex instead of a library PhonenumberField
Thank you anyway